# UITableView crashes when displaying data

Tags: objective-c, ios4, html-parsing, uitableview

i'm using hpple to parse a webpage content onto a table view and i'm having some issues. Im trying to display the parsed data which is stored in an NSArray onto the tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elements` is an array of `TFHppleElement` objects and you need to pass a `NSString` to `UILabel`'s `text` property. If you want to display the innerHTML content you can do this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[elements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] content];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting no text type of data to the textlable

cell.textLabel.text = [elements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

elements --- as per my understanding you are store some non string objects.